# Using Spring Repository in a Parallel Stream (Multi-threading)

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In a spring boot application, I have multiple implementations of an interface, every one of which accesses to the database using a JPA repository.

```
@Autowired
List<? extends CrawlerService> crawlers;
```

This is the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface HotelRepository extends JpaRepository<Hotel, Long> {
    public Optional<Hotel> findByTextAndSource(String text, String source);
}
```

And the implementations look like this:

```
@Service
public class MyService implements CrawlerService {

    @Autowired
    DocumentService documentService;

    @Autowired
    HotelRepository hotelRepository;

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("MyService");
    private Set<String> visitedLinks = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public void start() {
        execute("https://www.example.com/");
    }

    public void execute(String url) {
        if(visitedLinks.contains(url))
            return;

        try {
            logger.info("Connecting '{}' ...", url);
            visitedLinks.add(url);
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            String text = documentService.getText(document);

            // this is where I access to the database
            if(hotelRepository.findByTextAndSource(text, "EXAMPLE").isPresent()) {
                return;
            }

            Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
            hotel.setUrl(url);
            hotel.setText(text);
            hotel.setSource("EXAMPLE");
            hotelRepository.save(hotel);

            // find other links
            findLinks(document, url).forEach(this::execute);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Connection error for {}", url);
        }
    }

}
```

Now I'm using parallel stream to run each one of them in parallel:

```
crawlers.stream().parallel().forEach(CrawlerService::start);
```

They continue to work until the point that they want to access the database through the JPA repository. Then all of them stop, except the one assigned to the main thread. This is observed using the output of my logger:

`2018-11-01 21:42:38.408  INFO 7641 --- [           main] MyService ...`

Only this one continues to run.

I want all of them to continue to work in parallel. How can I solve this problem?

It is worth mentioning that I'm using MySQL and Spring Boot 2 with default settings for connection pool.

Comment: Do you use any database connections pool? What's the size of that pool?

Comment: @Ivan I didn't change anything, just using spring boot default settings.

Comment: I only assume that you have single db connection, thus only 1 session can be opened. Or you have some sort of table locking.

Comment: Spring-boot comes with a default connection pool (tomcat pooling, I think)

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @aka-one MySQL db

Comment: Please post the `start()` method code too. It may matter.

Comment: @aka-one nope, Hikari is the default one (since some v2***)

Comment: @Antoniossss Right, I also checked meanwhile.

Comment: @davidxxx I updated the question.

Comment: Debug suggestion :  Can you try once without parallel stream and see your code is working or not. Here could be two problem either your parallel stream getting blocked (as you know parallel streams use common fork-join thread pool and if you submit a long-running task, you effectively block all threads in the pool. Consequently you block all other tasks that are using parallel streams) or JPA configuration issue do to which you are not able to make DB call. Just a suggestion @Hamid Mohayeji.

Comment: Stupid question do all your implementations of `CrawlerService` try to process the same URL?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey because it's a crawler, it takes so long for each implementation to complete. But I know for sure that each one of them works fine individually. I'm still waiting too see what happens when the main thread completes it's work.

Comment: @Ivan no, each implementation of the interface process a specific website.